# Compile C++ to asm in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate assembly code from C++ source in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499199/how-to-generate-assembly-code-from-c-source-in-visual-studio-2010)

Hello.
How can I compile C++ code to asm in Visual Studio?

In gcc I just add one parampeter: -s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `/FAs` is the command-line argument.  There is also a setting in the GUI: http://codegem.org/2008/10/generate-assembly-from-c-code-in-visual-studio

Comment: It should be a forward slash, though. Still +1

Comment: @STATUS Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 5):

find project in solution explorer

right click properties

c/c++

output files

assembler output

Answer (score 4):

If you want to generate it from the IDE, goto project properties > C/C++ > Output files. In that you have an option called "Assembler Output". By default its set to "No Listing". Pull down the menu and select the option that suits you.