# Compiling C++ into Assembly Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate assembly code from C++ source in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499199/how-to-generate-assembly-code-from-c-source-in-visual-studio-2010)

Is it possible to compile C++ into assembly code in Visual Studio 2010 (or a free IDE) for a specific processor (for example, a microcontroller)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try CodeVision for Other Microprocessors. you can write C code for a Micro. ofcourse it's binary file is assembly for that micro.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja My understanding is that that question refers to the compilation of assembly code for the system the IDE is installed on, not a specific other processor.

Comment: Why was this closed?! It isn't a duplicate - it's importantly different!

Comment: @JonaGik- there has been quite a few people who voted to close it as the duplicate of FAQ. try checking it and if it doesnt answer your question repost or request answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be possible. i have converted c code to assembly.

Simply compile it with the option for an assembly listing.

use  /FA switch

this will generate the required assembly code but if you want it to be micro processor specific i think you need to do more research. Not all micro processors support same assembly codes. try using the generated assembly code in a simulator.